# Text in PHP echo won't show in browser

Tags: php

I use OS win10, xampp ( xampp manager already run and apache too) localhost and phpadmin run well. but when I write coding phpinfo.php like this coding

```
<?php 
phpinfo();
?php
```

in chrome will show same like that coding.
But if I add HTML format then in chrome will blank or not show any
it happens with coding

```
<HTML><BODY> <?php echo "Hello World!" ?> </BODY></HTML>
```

I already put there C:\xampp\htdocs but still don't show any. 
if I write code without html

```
<?php Echo " Hello World ! " ?>
```

then chrome show all script php code in browser.

is anyone can help me ? thanks a lot

Comment: first of all your code must be `<?php   phpinfo(); ?>`  and `<?php echo "Hello World !"; ?>`

Comment: @Anant: You don't need a semi-colon for one expression.

Comment: HTML and BODY not reference to this error not show... and a lot user already use in uppercase or lowercase but still same problem there

Comment: @Devon HTML is not case sensitive, but: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19808671/1737158

Comment: if your file extension is `.html` then change it to `.php`

Comment: Read answer in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page.

Comment: all file already in .php not in .html

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like there is something wrong with your configuration, here's a few things you can check:

1. Make sure that PHP is installed and running correctly. This may sound silly, but you never know. An easy way to check is to run `php -v` from a command line and see if returns version information or any errors.
2. Make sure that the PHP module is listed **and uncommented** inside of your Apache's httpd.conf This should be something like `LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"` in the file. Search for `LoadModule php`, and make sure that there is no comment (`;`) in front of it.
3. Make sure that the http.conf file has the PHP MIME type in it. This should be something like `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`. This tells Apache to run `.php` files as PHP. Search for AddType, and then make sure there is an entry for PHP, and that it is uncommented.
4. Make sure your file has the `.php` extension on it, or whichever extension specified in the MIME definition in point #3, otherwise it will not be executed as PHP.
5. Make sure you are not using short tags in the PHP file (`<?`), these are <del>deprecated</del> *not enabled on all servers* by default. Use `<?php` instead (or enable short tags in your php.ini whith `short_open_tag=On` if you have code that relies on them).
6. Make sure you are accessing your file over your webserver using an URL like `http://localhost/file.php` not via local file access `file://localhost/www/file.php`

And lastly check the [PHP manual for further setup tips](http://php.net/install).

Source: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page)